# how to hide a particular paragraph tag in layout in particular view p in rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

In my application I have a layout for all view pages ending with 'Happily, CSE team'. Now we have a view for destruction of user in that we want to display 'sadly, CSE team'. I know there is option, 'content_for tag' , I am having more than 20 views so no use of that tag.

In the user_destruction_mail view i want to display sadly cse team instead of  Sincerely, The Happy CSE team.

template.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
<title><%= content_for?(:page_title) ? yield(:page_title) : 'Mailer_View' %></title>
</head>

<body> 
  <table align="center"  cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >
              <tr>
                <td class="content-main" style="">
                  <%= yield %>

                  <p class="no-margin" style="padding:10px 0 0;">
                    Sincerely,<br />
                    The Happy CSE team
                  </p>

                </td>
              </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
```

view/intimation_mailers/user_destruction_mail.html.erb

```
<p>
Ciao,<br />
The Sadly CSE team
</p>
```

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: In the user_destruction_mail view i want to display sadly cse team instead of  Sincerely, The Happy CSE team.

Comment: Why not create a partial and use locals to determine what displays there ??

Comment: Actually my layout is quite large.

Comment: Does that really matter ?

Comment: Yea if i add partially i need to write a another layout!